# Should localhost be managed by systemd-networkd?

Tags: systemd, systemd-networkd

I am moving from NetworkManager to `systemd-networkd` (after an upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04). I configured all my interfaces, bridges and VLANs and everything works.

The log shows that

```
root@srv ~# journalctl -b | grep " lo" | grep networkd
May 20 10:55:44 srv systemd-networkd[765]: lo: Removing non-existent address: ::1/128 (valid forever), ignoring
May 20 10:55:44 srv systemd-networkd[765]: lo: Link is not managed by us
May 20 10:55:44 srv systemd-networkd[765]: lo: Link is not managed by us
May 20 10:55:44 srv systemd-networkd[765]: lo: Link is not managed by us
May 20 10:55:44 srv systemd-networkd-wait-online[801]: ignoring: lo
May 20 10:55:44 srv systemd-networkd-wait-online[801]: ignoring: lo
May 20 10:55:44 srv systemd-networkd[765]: lo: Link is not managed by us
May 20 10:55:44 srv systemd-networkd-wait-online[801]: ignoring: lo
May 20 10:55:44 srv systemd-networkd-wait-online[801]: ignoring: lo
May 20 10:55:44 srv systemd-networkd-wait-online[801]: ignoring: lo
May 20 10:55:44 srv systemd-networkd-wait-online[801]: ignoring: lo
May 20 10:55:44 srv systemd-networkd-wait-online[801]: ignoring: lo
```

(`ignoring: lo` is then repeated many times down the log)

First of all, `lo: Link is not managed by us`. It is managed by whom, then?

Then it looks like it is somehow set up correctly:

```
root@srv ~# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

It is indeed not managed by `systemd-networkd`:

```
root@srv ~# networkctl status lo
● 1: lo
       Link File: /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
    Network File: n/a
            Type: loopback
           State: carrier (unmanaged)
         Address: 127.0.0.1
```

But otherwise works as expected:

```
root@srv ~# ping localhost
PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.056 ms
```

**Should I configure it via `systemd-networkd` and if so - how?**

Comment: Did you have NetworkManger already installed?

Comment: @GAD3R: **TL;DR**: it is not installed right now. **DETAILS**: I had it installed when on Ubuntu 16.04, then migrated to 18.04, which uninstalled NetworkManager. Somehow (so that things do not break), networking was left in a strange state where the `network-manager` package is **not** installed but networking works (via `/etc/networking/interfaces & if-up & co.`). I removed `/etc/networking/interfaces` and disabled the `networking` service. And only then started to configure `systemd-networkd`. So it is not installed now.

Comment: @WoJ Did you ever find out how `lo` is managed?

Comment: @gxx: No. In the meantime I moved to Arch (because of the rolling updates) and the problem is not present there (it si still unmanaged, but there are no errors in the log). Sorry for not having more info.